# Which version of VBOX API does libvirt support?

Tags: virtualbox, libvirt

I have `libvirt` 1.3.5 and `virtualbox` 5.0.20 installed on my Gentoo system. When I start the `libvirtd` service, I got

```
Libvirt doesn't support VirtualBox API version 5000020
```

Where can I found out which vbox API does `libvirt` want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look in the source code. The libvirt version 1.3.5 doesn't support VirtualBox 5.

In [src/vbox/vbox_storage.c](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/v1.3.5/src/vbox/vbox_storage.c#L886)

```
virStorageDriverPtr vboxGetStorageDriver(uint32_t uVersion)
{
    /* Install gVBoxAPI according to the vbox API version.
     * Return -1 for unsupported version.
     */
    if (uVersion >= 2001052 && uVersion < 2002051) {
        vbox22InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 2002051 && uVersion < 3000051) {
        vbox30InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 3000051 && uVersion < 3001051) {
        vbox31InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 3001051 && uVersion < 3002051) {
        vbox32InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 3002051 && uVersion < 4000051) {
        vbox40InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4000051 && uVersion < 4001051) {
        vbox41InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4001051 && uVersion < 4002020) {
        vbox42InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4002020 && uVersion < 4002051) {
        vbox42_20InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4002051 && uVersion < 4003004) {
        vbox43InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4003004 && uVersion < 4003051) {
        vbox43_4InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
    return &vboxStorageDriver;
}
```

but the version 2.0.0 does. In [src/vbox/vbox_storage.c](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/v2.0.0/src/vbox/vbox_storage.c#L886)

```
virStorageDriverPtr vboxGetStorageDriver(uint32_t uVersion)
{
    /* Install gVBoxAPI according to the vbox API version.
     * Return -1 for unsupported version.
     */
    if (uVersion >= 2001052 && uVersion < 2002051) {
        vbox22InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 2002051 && uVersion < 3000051) {
        vbox30InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 3000051 && uVersion < 3001051) {
        vbox31InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 3001051 && uVersion < 3002051) {
        vbox32InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 3002051 && uVersion < 4000051) {
        vbox40InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4000051 && uVersion < 4001051) {
        vbox41InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4001051 && uVersion < 4002020) {
        vbox42InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4002020 && uVersion < 4002051) {
        vbox42_20InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4002051 && uVersion < 4003004) {
        vbox43InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4003004 && uVersion < 4003051) {
        vbox43_4InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else if (uVersion >= 4003051 && uVersion < 5000051) {
        vbox50InstallUniformedAPI(&gVBoxAPI);
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
    return &vboxStorageDriver;
}
```

Thanks to [this commit](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/commit/d0bef6433408745e4fffb9f16a146cbde9510f3b) published 14 days ago.

Comment: Lucky me...it is open source. Do they have a place to document stuffs?

Comment: On [this page](http://libvirt.org/news.html) you can see that support for VirtualBox 5 was added in libvirt 2.0.0 but it's almost easier to look in the source code.